# Using timthumb on WordPress , still not working:(( . Help,please

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my site,where the timthumb is not working :" http://vitinh.cz/?page_id=8 "
I have tried many solutions but nothing .... And i also used your tips in your website (http://andrewroycarter.com/wordpress-2/using-timthumb-on-wordpress-multi-user/ ).
 But I can not make it work anyway  :(.  Could you help me solve it ? Thank you .
I'm waiting forward to your answer.

(Wordpress  Version 3.0.1)

Comment: "Not working" is *not* a problem description. Without you doing some debugging and telling us about specific details you're stuck on it's impossible to answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to use timthumb.php to resize images that are not on your server.

The actual error for the resized images is this:

> remote host "ongmat.cz" not allowed
>   TimThumb version : 1.14

The solution is to edit the timthumb.php script and make a change to line 24 (or close to it)

```
 // external domains that are allowed to be displayed on your website
$allowedSites = array (
        'flickr.com',
        'picasa.com',
        'blogger.com',
        'wordpress.com',
        'img.youtube.com',
);
```

and add the domain you want to use images from, such as adding ongmat.cz to the array so it looks like this:

```
  $allowedSites = array (
                'flickr.com',
                'picasa.com',
                'blogger.com',
                'wordpress.com',
                'img.youtube.com',
                'ongmat.cz',
        );
```

or you can change this option (although not as secure)

```
define ('ALLOW_EXTERNAL', FALSE);                       // allow external website (override security precaution)
```

and change FALSE to TRUE

The first 30 lines should look like this:

```
/**
 * TimThumb script created by Ben Gillbanks, originally created by Tim McDaniels and Darren Hoyt
 * http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/
 * 
 * GNU General Public License, version 2
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Examples and documentation available on the project homepage
 * http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/
 */

define ('CACHE_SIZE', 250);                                     // number of files to store before clearing cache
define ('CACHE_CLEAR', 5);                                      // maximum number of files to delete on each cache clear
define ('CACHE_USE', FALSE);                            // use the cache files? (mostly for testing)
define ('VERSION', '1.16');                                     // version number (to force a cache refresh)
define ('DIRECTORY_CACHE', './cache');          // cache directory
define ('DIRECTORY_TEMP', './temp');            // temp directory
define ('MAX_WIDTH', 1000);                                     // maximum image width
define ('MAX_HEIGHT', 1000);                            // maximum image height
define ('ALLOW_EXTERNAL', TRUE);                       // allow external website (override security precaution)

// external domains that are allowed to be displayed on your website
$allowedSites = array (
        'flickr.com',
        'picasa.com',
        'blogger.com',
        'wordpress.com',
        'img.youtube.com',
        'ongmat.cz',
);
```

Comment: Then you are likely doing something wrong.  That is definitely the problem because I've had it before .  Can you post the first 30 lines of this file: http://vitinh.cz/wp-content/themes/vitinh/timthumb.php

Comment: if(!function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor')) {
    displayError('GD Library Error: imagecreatetruecolor does not exist - please contact your webhost and ask them to install the GD library');}
define ('CACHE_SIZE', 250); 
define ('CACHE_CLEAR', 5);   
define ('VERSION', '1.14');   
define ('DIRECTORY_CACHE', './cache');  
define ('DIRECTORY_TEMP', './temp');  
$allowedSites = array ( 
        'flickr.com', 
        'picasa.com', 
        'blogger.com', 
        'wordpress.com', 
        'img.youtube.com', 
        'ongmat.cz', 
); 

Sorry , i can not post like u

Comment: alternatively you can upload the images to your own blog and link to them that way.

Comment: I have added exactly like above but nothing happen :(

Comment: Create a backup copy of the file, and then replace the lines of code with the ones I pasted and see if that solves it.  If not, put back the backup copy

Comment: I have read the code at : http://timthumb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/timthumb.php  and also have done as what u told me, still not work :(